# Is it safe to access Elasticseach from a client without going through an API server?

Tags: reactjs, api, security, elasticsearch, vue.js

For example, suppose you embed the following Javascript code in Vue.js or React.js.

```
var elasticsearch = require ('elasticsearch');
var esclient = new elasticsearch.Client ({
   host: 'Elasticsearch host name of Elascticsearch Cloud's(URL?')
   });
   esclient.search ({
         index: 'your index',
           body: {
             query: {
              match: {message: 'search keyword'}
   },
   aggs: {
       your_states: {
          terms: {
            field: 'your field',
            size: 10
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
 ).then (function (response) {
       var hits = response.hits.hits;
 }
);
```

When aiming at a search engine of an application like stackoverflow,
if only GET from the public is OK by using the ROLE setting of the cloud of Elasticseach,
Even though I did not prepare an API server, I thought that the same thing could be realized with the above client side code,
Is it a security problem? (Such as whether it is dangerous for the host name to fall on the client side)

If there is no problem, the search engine response will be faster and the cost of implementation will be reduced,
I wondered why many people would not do it. (Because sample code like this can not be seen on the net much)

Thank you.

Comment: Well, exposing ES to the outside is strongly discouraged, especially if you are not using XPack Security, anyone can do anything to your data since ES has no security built-in.

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT a good idea.

If any client with a bit of programming knowledge finds our your ElasticSearch IP address, you are screwed, he could basically delete all the data without you even noticing.

I have no understanding about XPack Security, but if you are not using that you are absolutely forced to hide ES behind an API.

Then you also have to secure you ES domain to allow access only from the API server and block the rest of the world.

Comment: I think that if you set the ROLE of the cloud that is running Elasticsearch so that outside people can only GET, there is no problem. That way, outside people can not do DELETE, UPDATAE, POST, too. How is that?

Comment: Better, but I'd still add a layer in between. Maybe you don't need an API, but putting an NGINX instance in between so that you can throttle requests would still be a good idea

Comment: Thanks.
However, if you allow only GET, is the security level almost the same as there is an API server?